# Editing the loop for Author pages

Tags: author, loop

I was wondering if anyone can help me out. I am looking to remove the_content part of the loop on **my author pages only**.  So basically, I just want a list of the author posts with only the title and meta instead of the full post.

When I went to the author.php file, I found this, which I believe is the code that is generating the posts on the Author Pages.

```
/* Run the loop for the author archive page to output the authors posts
 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
 * called loop-author.php and that will be used instead.
 */
     get_template_part( 'loop', 'author' );
```

I'm pretty new at this, so please bare with me.

My question is, how I do I remove the content from the loop for only the Author pages.  I wouldn't think that I should remove the function that generates the content from the loop.php file because that would remove it from all posts on my site.

The comments above say, If I want to overload this in a child theme, the include a file called loop-author.php.  Can I simply copy all the code from the loop.php file into a new loop-author file, remove the function that generates content from there?  Would i have to change any of the parameters in the get_template_part() function?

Again, really new at doing this, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Parent Theme, has a template file `loop-author.php`, copy it to your Child Theme; otherwise, copy your Parent Theme's `loop.php` template file to your Child Theme, and rename it as `loop-author.php`.

Now, modify your Child Theme's `loop-author.php` template file, in whatever way you wish.

You don't need to make *any other changes*, either to the Parent Theme or to your Child Theme. The Parent Theme already accounts for a Child Theme's use of `loop-author.php`, based on its call to `get_template_part( 'loop', 'author' );`.

The way such a call works is this: WordPress will look for files in the following order, until it finds one that exists:

1. Child Theme `loop-author.php`
2. Parent Theme `loop-author.php`
3. Child Theme `loop.php`
4. Parent Theme `loop.php`

Thus, you see the power and flexibility of `get_template_part()`!